# How to define a function that returns a list or a single element in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm completely stuck trying to implement this function below in a simple tutorial [exercise](https://haskell.mooc.fi/part1#exercises-2). It should apply the second parameter to the last parameter, and then apply the first parameter to the whole thing:

```hs
multiApp sum     [(1+), (^3), (+2)]      1       ==>  6
multiApp reverse [tail, take 2, reverse] "foo"   ==> ["oof","fo","oo"]
```

Since the function can return a single element or list, I don't know how to define it, something like this as a start won't even compile:

```hs
multiApp :: (β->β) -> [(β->β)] -> β    -> β
multiApp f fs x = f $ map (\i -> i x) fs
```

Comment: Your `multiApp` type does not fit to your implementation. You probably meant `multiApp :: ([β]->β) -> [(β->β)] -> β -> β`, that is `[β]` instead of `β` in the first argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You work with an unnecessary restriction on `f`: you here say `f` has type `β -> β`, but why do the input and output types of `f` need to be of the same type?

You can generalize to:

```
multiApp :: ([α] -> β) -> [α -> α] -> α -> β
multiApp f fs x = f $ map ($ x) fs
```

You thus apply each function in the list to the value, and then you call `f` on the list of these items. For `sum` this will thus sum up the elements, whereas for `reverse`, it will reverse the list.

We can in fact further generalize this to:

```
multiApp :: ([β] -> γ) -> [α -> β] -> α -> γ
multiApp f fs x = f $ map ($ x) fs
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you say `multiApp :: ([α] -> β) ` instead of `multiApp :: (α -> β) `?

Comment: @Richard: because `map ($ x) fs` will produce a list of `α`s.

Comment: Ok, the function failed on the last test `multiApp sum [head, last] [1,2,3,4]` so I had to generalise the definition even more to `multiApp :: ([ψ]->φ) -> [β->ψ] -> β -> φ`. Thank you for your help! These abstractions are tough.